# amplify:flutter:auth_cognito: InvalidParameterException

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito

I am working on a mobile application using flutter.
I have no clue how I would be able to solve this problem.
I am using AWS Cognito for user verification

This is my code

```
void _signUp() {
    final username = _usernameController.text.trim();
    final password = _passwordController.text.trim();
    final passwordConfirm = _passwordConfirmController.text.trim();
    final email = _emailController.text.trim();
    final gender = _isGenderSelected[0] == true ? 'male' : 'female';
    final birthMonth = _birthMonthController!.length <= 1 ? '0' + _birthMonthController! : _birthMonthController!;
    final birthDay = _birthDayController!.length <= 1 ? '0' + _birthDayController! : _birthDayController!;
    final birthdate = '$birthMonth/$birthDay/$_birthYearController';

    print('username: $username');
    print('password: $password');
    print('password confirm: $passwordConfirm');
    print('email: $email');
    print('gender: $gender');
    print('birthdate: $birthdate');

    if (password == passwordConfirm) {
      final credentials = SignUpCredentials(
          username: username,
          password: password,
          email: email,
          gender: gender,
          birthdate: birthdate
      );
      widget.didProvideCredentials(credentials);
    }
    else
      print('Password does not match');
  }
```

And this is the error that I get in the run console

```
I/flutter (13290): username: gs97ahn
I/flutter (13290): password: 1234567890
I/flutter (13290): password confirm: 1234567890
I/flutter (13290): email: gs97ahn@naver.com
I/flutter (13290): gender: male
I/flutter (13290): birthdate: 02/11/1997
E/UserContextDataProvider(13290): Exception in creating JSON from context data
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(13290): InvalidParameterException
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(13290): InvalidParameterException{message=One or more parameters are incorrect., cause=com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'custom:birthdate:' at 'attributes.3.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_.-]+(:[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_.-]+)*$ (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: a41e4c3c-09eb-401a-9891-f957ce0004c3), recoverySuggestion=Enter correct parameters.}
```

Answer (score 0):

The birthdate you are providing:

> birthdate: 02/11/1997

is not matching the regular expression pattern of Cognito for this attribute:

> ^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}*.-]+(:[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}*.-]+)*$

You should change the date format, or change the regular expression.

Comment: Problem is fixed... it was the parameter field which was suppose to be 'birthdate' : but I had it like 'birthdate:' : .... Thanks though... actually took me more than 7hours for me to figure it out :(